# Python replace empty strings in a list with values from a different list

Tags: python

I'm looking for a slick / elegant way that would replace `" "` in one list with values from other list i.e.:

```
empty_list = [" ", " ", " "]
other_list = ["a", "b"]
result_list = ["a", "b", " "]
```

P.S. I'm not looking for a `for` loop solution

Comment: Are you guaranteed that `other_list` is always smaller than `empty_list` ?

Comment: What would be the result for `empty_list = [" ", "foo", " "]`? `["a", "foo", "b"]` or `["a", "foo", " "]`?

Comment: Why no `for` loops?  You're going to get some really weird solutions to a simple problem.

Comment: @scharette no, and you should take care of this case as well =)

Comment: @scharette, empty list will always be larger or equal in size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
empty_list = [" ", " ", " "]
other_list = iter(["a", "b"])

lst = [x if x != ' ' else next(other_list, x) for x in empty_list]

print(lst)
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'b', ' ']
```

Comment: why 'b', 'a', when OP asks for 'a', 'b' ??

Comment: i changed it :)

Comment: `x if x != ' ' else other_list.pop(0) if len(other_list) else x` Yuk. How about making `other_list` an `iter` and then `x if x != ' ' else next(other_iter, x)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
new_list = [ a if b == ' ' else b for a,b in zip( other_list, empty_list)]
new_list += empty_list[len(other_list):]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just slice the first list if empty_list only contains `" "` blanks

```
empty_list = [" ", " ", " "]
other_list = ["a", "b"]
print([i for i in other_list if len(i)>0]+empty_list[len(other_list):])
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', ' ']
```

Comment: This assumes that `empty_list` is in fact a list of only `' '`. IF this is the case, then this will work, and indeed be the best solution, but that's one big IF. (not my downvote, btw)

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem as stated, merely provides the correct answer for these inputs.

Comment: @tobias_k empty_list as the name suggest and not clarified by the OP should contain only blanks. I am just following the post to not use for loop. Can't get anything better than this.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I don't understand what problem it will not solve? Can you explain please?